# Why is the return value from function A called differently in function B?

Tags: javascript, variables, return

```js
function rollClass() {

  // Select a physical or magical god as well as its class
  var classList = new Array();
  classList[0] = 0; // Physical Hunter
  classList[1] = 1; // Physical Warrior
  classList[2] = 2; // Physical Assassin
  classList[3] = 3; // Magical Mage
  classList[4] = 4; // Magical Guardian

  // Computer shit to select an option
  var ran = Math.random(); // Create a new random number to truly randomize it

  var i = Math.floor(classList.length * ran);

  // Write it onto the developer log:
  document.getElementById("dLog1").innerHTML = "The variable i in function rollClass() is: " + i;

  // Sends the variable classList[i] to B
  var a = classList[i];

  // Write onto dLog #3. Test to see what variabe "a" shows up as
  document.getElementById("dLog3").innerHTML = "The variable a in function rollClass() is: " + a;

  // Output classList[i]
  return a;
}

// Stating the check class function first. Doesn't make a difference.
function checkClass() {

  // Grab classList[i] (var a) from function rollClass();
  var r = rollClass();

  var dLog = "Class";

  // Write out what r is in checkClass(r)
  // Developer log 5
  document.getElementById("dLog5").innerHTML = "The r in checkClass(r) is " + r;

  // Determine if it is a physical or magical god as well as its class
  if (r == 0) {
    // This is a physical hunter
    var type = "Physical";
    var typeC = "Hunter";
    var dLog = "Hunter";
  } else if (r == 1) {
    // This is a physical warrior
    var type = "Physical";
    var typeC = "Warrior";
    var dLog = "Warrior";
  } else if (r == 2) {
    // This is a physical assassin
    var type = "Physical";
    var typeC = "Assassin";
    var dLog = "Assassin";
  } else if (r == 3) {
    // This is a magical mage
    var type = "Magical";
    var typeC = "Mage";
    var dLog = "Mage";
  } else {
    // Assume it's a magical guardian
    var type = "Magical";
    var typeC = "Guardian";
    var dLog = "Guardian";
  }

  // Developer log
  document.getElementById("dLog2").innerHTML = "The value for classList[i]: " + dLog;

  // Sets variables for transfer to another function
  var a = type;
  var b = typeC;

  // Developer log 7, show what var a and variable b are
  document.getElementById("dLog7").innerHTML = "Variable a: " + a + "<br>Variable b: " + b;

  return [a, b];
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GOD ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Function to determine god. Creates an array list and then determines the god.
// t = type
// c = class
function rollGod() {

  var array = checkClass();
  var c = array[1];

  // the list of gods

  // Determine what the computer chose
  if (c == "Hunter") {
    // Hunter
    // There are 19 hunters
    var god = new Array(); // Array for hunters
    god[0] = "Ah Muzen Cab";
    god[1] = "Anhur";
    god[2] = "Apollo";
    god[3] = "Artemis";
    god[4] = "Cernunnos";
    god[5] = "Chernobog";
    god[6] = "Chiron";
    god[7] = "Cupid";
    god[8] = "Hachiman";
    god[9] = "Heimdallr";
    god[10] = "Hou Yi";
    god[11] = "Izanami";
    god[12] = "Jing Wei";
    god[13] = "Medusa";
    god[14] = "Neith";
    god[15] = "Rama";
    god[16] = "Skadi";
    god[17] = "Ullr";
    god[18] = "Xbalanque";
  } else if (c == "Warrior") {
    // Warrior
    // There are 16 warriors
    var god = new Array();
    god[0] = "Achilles";
    god[1] = "Amaterasu";
    god[2] = "Bellona";
    god[3] = "Vamana";
    god[4] = "Tyr";
    god[5] = "Sun Wukong";
    god[6] = "Nike";
    god[7] = "Odin";
    god[8] = "Osiris";
    god[9] = "Hercules";
    god[10] = "Horus";
    god[11] = "Cu Chulainn";
    god[12] = "Chaac";
    god[13] = "Erlang Shen";
    god[14] = "Guan Yu";
    god[15] = "King Arthur";

  } else if (c == "Assassin") {
    // Assassin
    // There are 21 assassins
    var god = new Array();
    god[0] = "Arachne"; //     
    god[1] = "Awilix";
    god[2] = "Bakasura";
    god[3] = "Bastet";
    god[4] = "Camazotz";
    god[5] = "Da Ji";
    god[6] = "Fenrir";
    god[7] = "Hun Batz";
    god[8] = "Kali";
    god[9] = "Loki";
    god[10] = "Mercury";
    god[11] = "Ne Zha";
    god[12] = "Nemesis";
    god[13] = "Pele";
    god[14] = "Ratatoskr";
    god[15] = "Ravana";
    god[16] = "Serqet";
    god[17] = "Set";
    god[18] = "Susano";
    god[19] = "Thanatos";
    god[20] = "Thor";

  } else if (c == "Mage") {
    // Mage
    // 32 Mages in the list currently
    var god = new Array();
    god[0] = "Agni";
    god[1] = "Ah Puch";
    god[2] = "Anubis";
    god[3] = "Ao Kuang";
    god[4] = "Aphrodite";
    god[5] = "Baron Samedi";
    god[6] = "Chang'e";
    god[7] = "Chronos";
    god[8] = "Discordia";
    god[9] = "Freya";
    god[10] = "Hades";
    god[11] = "He Bo";
    god[12] = "Hel";
    god[13] = "Hera";
    god[14] = "Isis";
    god[15] = "Janus";
    god[16] = "Kukulkan";
    god[17] = "Merlin";
    god[18] = "Nox";
    god[19] = "Nu Wa";
    god[20] = "Olorun";
    god[21] = "Persphone";
    god[22] = "Poseidon";
    god[23] = "Ra";
    god[24] = "Raijin";
    god[25] = "Scylla";
    god[26] = "Sol";
    god[27] = "The Morrigan";
    god[28] = "Thoth";
    god[29] = "Vulcan";
    god[30] = "Zeus";
    god[31] = "Zhong Kui";

  } else {
    // Guardian
    // There are 19 guardians
    var god = new Array();
    god[0] = "Ares"; //     
    god[1] = "Artio";
    god[2] = "Athena";
    god[3] = "Bacchus";
    god[4] = "Cabrakan";
    god[5] = "Cerberus";
    god[6] = "Fafnir";
    god[7] = "Ganesha";
    god[8] = "Geb";
    god[9] = "Jormungandr";
    god[10] = "Khepri";
    god[11] = "Kumbhakarna";
    god[12] = "Kuzenbo";
    god[13] = "Sobek";
    god[14] = "Sylvanus";
    god[15] = "Terra";
    god[16] = "Xing Tian";
    god[17] = "Yemoja";
    god[18] = "Ymir";
  }

  // Math shit
  var ran = Math.random();
  var zed = Math.floor(god.length * ran);

  // Output
  document.getElementById("god").innerHTML = god[zed];

  return god[zed];

} // End of god function

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BOOTS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function rollBoots() {
  // Choosing boots

  // Calls the result of the function checkClass
  var array = checkClass();
  var type = array[0];

  // dLog6, show what array[0] is
  document.getElementById("dLog6").innerHTML = "Developer log 6: " + type;

  var god = rollGod();

  // Determine what kind of god it is
  // Physical God
  if (type == "Physical") {
    // Test if it's Rat, if not continue
    if (god == "Ratatoskr") {
      var boot = new Array()
      boot[0] = "Acorn";
    } else {
      var boot = new Array();
      boot[0] = "Warrior Tabi";
      boot[1] = "Ninja Tabi";
      boot[2] = "Reinforced Greaves";
      boot[3] = "Talaria Boots";
    }
  } // End of if statement
  // Magical God
  else {
    var boot = new Array();
    boot[0] = "Shoes of Magi";
    boot[1] = "Shoes of Focus";
    boot[2] = "Reinforced Shoes";
    boot[3] = "Traveler Shoes";
  } // End of else statement

  // Output
  // Math and computer shit
  var ran = Math.random();
  var i = Math.floor(boot.length * ran);

  // Write it out
  document.getElementById("boots").innerHTML = boot[i];
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// First time opening the script
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function to create a class array and select a class
rollClass();
checkClass();
rollBoots();
```

```html
<p1>God: </p1>
<div align="center" ;>
  <p2 id="god">God Here</p2>
</div>
<br>
<p1>Boots: </p1>
<div align="center" ;>
  <p2 id="boots">Boots Here</p2>
</div>

<p> Developer log: </p>
<p id="dLog1"> This shows the i value for variable: classList </p>
<p id="dLog3"> dLog3 </p>
<p id="dLog2"> dLog2 </p>
<p id="dLog4"> dLog4 </p>
<p id="dLog5"> dLog5 </p>
<p id="dLog6"> dLog6 </p>
<p id="dLog7"> dLog7 </p>
```

I have a function `checkClass()` to determine variables `type` and `typeC`. The function `checkClass()` returns those two variables. Variable `type` should only be `"Physical"` or `"Magical"`.

I then have a second function `rollBoots()` that only wants variable `type`. For some reason, the return values are switched in the function `rollBoots()`. For example, `checkClass()` has variable `type = "Physical"`. However, when it is called in function `rollBoots()`, variable `type = "Magical"`.

I turned function `checkClass()` into an array so that it can be called in other functions. In a different function, the variable `typeC` works fine. I also saw that the function `checkClass()` correctly outputted the expected variables. But somewhere along the way the variable `type` gets mixed up.

The current output is that a `Magical` is selected but it creates an array from the `Physical` array list (Warrior Tabi, Ninja Tabi, etc.).

From the snippet code, Developer Log 6 and Variable a should display the same. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: In a function, any given variable only needs one `var` declaration.

Comment: What does `rollClass` do? If it's random, it's quite expected that subsequent invocations will return different results. How often (where else other than in `rollBoots`) are you calling `checkClass()`?

Comment: You don't need to declare different variables just to return the values. You can do `return [type, typeC];`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Bergi ```rollClass``` is random, but I'm pretty sure I only called it once at the end of my code. I don't have ```rollClass``` called in any other function. I'm trying to keep every function separate so that I can use buttons to reroll certain things. I added a snippet of my code.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean I declare ```var a = 10``` and then I can just use something like ```var b = a + a```?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your comment. I will make the changes onto my code. Probably will make things neater anyway.

I also added the reproducible example via Stack Snippet. The main thing that should be most paid attention is at the bottom of the snippet ```Developer Log 6``` and ```variable a``` should display the same thing. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: You're calling `checkClass()` twice: once from `rollBoots()` and once from `rollGod()`. `dlog6` shows the value from `rollBoots()`, but `dlog7` is overwritten every time `checkClass()` is called. That's why they're different.

Comment: @BeggerStager What Barmar said. And you call it a third time at the end of your code. What you should do is to *not* call it from inside `rollBoots` and `rollGod`, but have them take the class as a parameter. Then at the end of your code, do `const c = rollClass(); const boots = rollBoots(c); const god = rollGod(c);`.

Comment: @Barmar @Bergi First off, thanks you guys. I'm starting to understand what the problem was. The thing is, my function ```checkClass``` returns two variables. How do I call ```variable 1``` to ```functionA``` and ```variable 2``` to ```functionB```? Both variables are ```return```ed from the ```checkClass``` function. Ex: ```return [variable1, variable2]``` ... ```functionA(variable1) functionB(variable2)```

Comment: Call it once before you call either function A or function B, and pass the appropriate parts as parameters to those functions.